# Deploy Symfony2 application with Capifony failes on assetic dump

Tags: symfony, capistrano, assets, assetic, continuous-deployment

For unknown reason my deployment process fails on assetic dump. Tried debugging with no success. If I turn assetic dump off - it succeeds. This is executed by Jenkins CI

This project uses SASS, compass for assetic dump.
If running over cli (same server as Jenkins is on) - it succeeds.

```
capifony_copy_local strategy
explicit settings for php
```

The output of deployment:

```
cap HOSTS=www-node1.domain.com production deploy
--> Updating code base with capifony_copy_local strategy
--> Using Copy Local Strategy
--> Downloading Composer to temp location...................✔

--> Installing Composer dependencies in temp location.......✔

--> Building bootstrap file in temp location................✔

--> Creating cache directory................................✔

--> Creating symlinks for shared directories................✔

--> Creating symlinks for shared files......................✔

--> Normalizing asset timestamps............................✔

--> Dumping all assets to the filesystem....................✘
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/portal/releases/20140315133521 && /usr/bin/php app/console assets:dump --env=prod'" on www-node1.domain.com
```

IF assetic:dump process not enabled - it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deployment in debug mode? `cap deploy -d` executes one task at a time. You can check the deployment just before capistrano executes the `assetic:dump` command. At this point I would run assetic:dump by hand and check what errors are thrown.

Comment: I had to execute it in command line.
--> Dumping all assets to the filesystem....................Preparing to execute command: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/portal/releases/20140315163620 && /usr/bin/php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod '"
Execute ([Yes], No, Abort) ?  |y|  
✔

So it succeeds when executing from command line but still fails when Jenkins executes it.

I am unable to add '-d' to CI because there is no way to go over steps.

Answer (score 0):

Does `Jenkins` has the permission to write to this directory?

If it does, this reminds me of an error I had about a month ago: `assetic:dump` command failed due to missing `LESS` compiler. This happened to me during the first-time deploy but failed silently, same as it did to you.

Do you happen to use `LESS` or any similar utility (`SASS`, `YUI`, `UglifyJS`...)? If so, check that user has appropriate privileges to execute it or that utility was not installed per-user (instead of globally)...

Comment: Very good idea. yui compressor included in repository. Less, sass and compass exists on production server. The strangest thing is that I can run assetic:dumo on production (in case when I disable assetic:dump on project and deploy using Jenkins). Also it works if I deploy from jenkins server manuall (executing command as jenkins user)